# Can Code triggered by Chatter-Free user run in System mode?

Tags: apex, security, sharing, licenses, crud

I am exposing some code to `Chatter Free` user which modifies `Account` objects. I know that Chatter Free users are not directly able to modify them.

1. But can my trigger code do it on behalf of them? As Apex code runs
   in **System mode**.
2. Do I need a `without sharing` even if this is more
   about CRUD?
3. And which user will be in the `LastModifiedBy` field if
   this works?

Comment: Would it make sense to set a field on the record that triggered the event and have a scheduled batch job do the change. Or is it a requirement that it is real-time?
Could you perpaps tell a bit more about it?

Comment: @ChristianJuul  Must be real time.

Comment: is this not equivalent to a sites guest user who also can't do CRUD on Account but that works just fine with a class defined `without sharing`?